# Upgrade from spring-security-kerberos-core 1.0.0.M2

Tags: spring-security-kerberos

I just discovered work on Spring Security Kerberos/SPNEGO Extension on github: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-kerberos

Since we still use 1.0.0.M2, I wonder if an update is recommended or where I can see how development on the new release is planned and making progress.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to update as well. The maven dependency link is broken at the moment (the one stated on http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-kerberos/). However the content is identical with 1.0.0.M2 anyway except for the packaging.

For that reason updating does not seem to be necessary.